# Magento 2: Change product template based on the category

Tags: magento2, product, magento2.4, product-detail-page, catalog-prodct-view.xml

We have multiple categories and each category has it's own products(mostly simple products). The products in each category has different UI design for product view page / product details page.

I know it is possible to change the product view layout based on the product id or sku or product type or for all products - [Product layouts](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/product-layouts.html). But, is it possible to change the layout based on the products' category? Or is there any way we can change the layout design for a specific set of products.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Here’s the step-by-step process to change the product page layout in Magento 2.

**Step #1**
First of all, we will have to create a di.xml file to add the plugin in `app/code/Gohil/Rajesh/etc/frontend/` directory and add the following code into the file.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Created By : Gohil Rajesh
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
   <type name="Magento\Catalog\Controller\Product\View">
      <plugin name="Gohil_Rajesh::change_product_view" type="Gohil\Rajesh\Plugin\Catalog\Controller\Product\View" sortOrder="1" />
   </type>
</config>
```

**Step #2**
Next, we will also have to create a View.php file for the plugin in the app/code/Gohil/Rajesh/Plugin/Catalog/Controller/Product/ directory and copy the following code in the file.

```
<?php
/**
 * Created By : Gohil Rajesh
 */
namespace Gohil\Rajesh\Plugin\Catalog\Controller\Product;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException;
class View
{
    /**
     * @var RequestInterface
     */
    private $request;
    /**
     * @var ProductRepositoryInterface
     */
    private $productRepository;
    /**
     * @var StoreManagerInterface
     */
    private $storeManager;
    /**
     * @param RequestInterface           $request
     * @param ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository
     * @param StoreManagerInterface      $storeManager
     */
    public function __construct(
        RequestInterface $request,
        ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository,
        StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
    ) {
        $this->request = $request;
        $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
    }
    public function afterExecute(\Magento\Catalog\Controller\Product\View $subject, $resultPage)
    {
        if ($resultPage instanceof ResultInterface)

        {
            $productId = (int) $this->request->getParam('id');
            if ($productId)
            {
                try
                {
                    $product = $this->productRepository->getById($productId, false, $this->storeManager->getStore()->getId());
                    if (Your Condition)
                    {
                        $pageConfig = $resultPage->getConfig();
                        $pageConfig->setPageLayout('2columns-right'); //Set your page layout here.
                    }
                }
                catch (NoSuchEntityException $e)
                {
                    // Add you exception message here.
                }
            }
        }
        return $resultPage;
    }
}
```

In the above plugin file, you’ll need to set your desired layout in the setPageLayout().

But in our example, we will set the product page layout to be displayed 2 columns-right if condition is true

So, once you set your desired layout, the last thing you need to do is clean the cache and check the output.